# Issue in calling Get Method of a Rest API on web in my Xamarin.Forms code

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, web-api-testing

I am trying to consume a Get method from a random WebAPI on the Web through my `Xamarin.Forms` code. But I am not able to call that API. Can someone please help. Here is my code:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    try
    {
        var todos = GetAPIDataFromWeb();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
    }
}

private async Task<List<Todo>> GetAPIDataFromWeb()
{
    List<Todo> todos = new List<Todo>();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
    if (response != null)
    {
        todos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Todo>>(response);
        todoListView.ItemsSource = todos;
    }
    return todos;
}
```

When I debug, the control comes out from

```
var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
```

the statement, i.e. this statement never executes. It doesn't throw any exception(so, the control never hits the catch block in the caller method), it's just that the control skips the remaining statements and hits the closing curly braces of try block of the caller method.

PS - I am running this code on my own android device(which is connected to the wifi)

Comment: first - when you make method "async void" you simply make it "fire and forget" - there is no way to determine if it was fired. It's always better to make `async Task` methods if you don't want to return any result.

secondly - tour Try-catch catches all exceptions and does nothing. possibly there may be some exception thrown in your code, it is cough and hidden - avoid empty catches - at least log something for you to know that exception have been thrown.

and lastly - if you override some method, it's wise to call base implementation - otherwise some logic may not be called

Comment: Thanks will update it. The control doesn't even go into the catch block, i.e. no exception is throws, it just exits! The main issue remains unsolved - why is the API not getting called!?

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting? I am able to get response with your code

Comment: @ayon.gupta how are you able to get the response? Are you able to get the response via Xamarin code? I am not getting any exception, please check my edits.

Comment: Please check this image https://postimg.cc/K4HrR8x9

Comment: @ayon.gupta, not sure why it is not working for me. BTW, I am running this code from my own android device(which is connected to the wifi).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, but the jist of the problem is that you are making threading calls incorrectly that make it difficult for you to handle exception that may be thrown by your code including deadlocks and cross thread access to controls.

Your code needs to be refactored

```
static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
event EventHandler appearing = delegate { };

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    appearing += onAppearing; //subscribe
    onAppearing(this, EventArgs.Empty);  //raise event      
}

private async void onAppearing(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    appearing -= onAppearing; //unsubscribe
    try {//On UI Thread
        var todos = await GetAPIDataFromWeb(); //Background Thread
        todoListView.ItemsSource = todos; //Back on UI Thread
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
    }        
}

private async Task<List<Todo>> GetAPIDataFromWeb() {
    List<Todo> todos = new List<Todo>();
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    if (response != null) {
        todos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Todo>>(response);            
    }
    return todos;
}
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: thanks for the insights and code, but it still isn't working for me. I have tried your code, entirely.

Comment: No it doesn't show any error. It just comes out of the statement.

Comment: my Git commit of the same for your reference - https://github.com/Abhishek5Kumar/WebAPIFromXamarin

Comment: @AbhishekKumar will check it when I get a chance. I would suggest in the mean time you also check the URL you are calling. Notice how I changed it to call the collection. In your example you are trying to parse one todo item into a collection which would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that all UI changes must be dane in the main thread. in your case `GetAPIDataFromWeb` is done in other thread, so tle line `todoListView.ItemsSource = todos;` may have difficulties in updating UI. to solve this issue chose following solutions:

1. UI Blocking one - your `GetAPIDataFromWeb` should return list of items. in OnAppearing you are awaiting this result and apply changes to UI element (see ansfer from Nkosi). Problem is that in such case you block users UI for the time of request. It's bad solution in my opinion.
2. You use benefit of Binding or INotifyPropertyChange interface. In view you bind your `todoListView.ItemsSource` either to some property and throw needed event to inform UI about data binding change `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` if the code you provided is done in ViewModel. if it is done directly in codeBehind, you should create specyfic Bindable property and set it's value.

Creating Bindable property is done this way:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ToDoListProperty = 
            BindableProperty.Create("nameYouWillUseInXaml", typeof(List<Todo>), typeof({TourCodeBegindClassHere}),
                default(int), Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.OneWay);
```

ant then in the `GetAPIDataFromWeb` method you want to set value change 
`todoListView.ItemsSource = todos;` to:

```
SetValue(ToDoListProperty , todos);
```